# PyString_AsStringAndSize: Warring w.r.t to function signature

Tags: python, c, cython

I am using PyString_AsStringAndSize as shown below.

```
cdef char * data
cdef int datalen
PyString_AsStringAndSize(filedata, &data, &datalen)
```

filedata is a python object. I am getting a "warning: passing argument 3 of 'PyString_AsStringAndSize' from incompatible pointer type".

From PyString_AsStringAndSize api guide, it looks like &datalen should be Py_ssize_t *.

If I change datalen to of type, I am getting error "Cannot assign type 'unsigned int (*)' to 'int (*)'". Any pointers to fix this warning.

Comment: Is there are reason not to define `datalen` as `Py_ssize_t`?

Comment: I had tried Py_ssize_t. Compiler cribbed  "Cannot assign type 'Py_ssize_t (*)' to 'int (*)'". I am a new bee to Cython. Could not conclude why PyString_AsStringAndSize is expecting int (*).

Comment: PyString_AsStringAndSize() is expecting a `Py_ssize_t *`, not an `int *`: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html#c.PyString_AsStringAndSize. It needs the pointer to store the length of the string, the second parameter is a *return parameter*. You are getting the warning because `sizeof(Py_ssize_t)` need not be `sizeof(int)`. If you try to convert the value to an `int`, the conversion is possibly lossy.